# My three little friends - a riddle with a story

Tags: riddle, story

---

Hi everyone, solve this riddle:
I have three friends, they're all little...
another world is where they live,
wherein there can be no eclipse.

My closest friend is the first one,
always follows me every day...
Though he's not coloured black and white,
I call him "Felix" anyway.

My second friend is much distinct,
he looks otherworldly and strange...
If you assemble him, first think,
once he is formed, back he can't change.

My third friend, so much has she changed...
A beautiful healer she was,
but her powers have much mutated,
and now in father's house she is.

You might be confused, what to seek...
To solve this, my words you must heed:
Get to know my friends well and think;
a primal sum is what you need.

---

Hint 1

> My second friend has many kids,
> hatched from eggs rock-encrusted...
> Any three of them you will need,
> with them he can be "assembled".

Hint 2

> My third friend, she was very quick,
> when someone called, she'd work at once...
> But now she always waits a tick,
> I'm worried her work someone cuts.

Hint 3 (continued from Hint 2)

> She can heal still, but changed it has...
> Back then it very simple was,
> But now it more progressive is...
> Many people like her more thus.

Comment: First opinion: Primal sum-> you are referring to some ancient infinite sum... maybe. Also, once he is formed, back he can't change, kind of breaks my hypothesis above, but that's my first impression.

Comment: @user351579 :( interesting.

Comment: I feel like this has something to do with Gotrek and Felix.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks Gotrek? What's Gotrek?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotrek_and_Felix

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks No, not _that_ Felix.

Comment: anthing to do with elements?

Comment: Sounds like they could possibly be Pokémon.

Comment: Is this question specific to a game, movie, etc.? Or is it a fairly common 'thing' or person, object,  entity, etc.

Comment: Yes, but there's side reference. And figuring out the works ref'd does not automatically bring you to the answer.

Comment: First Friend is a "cat" @user351579

Comment: @KRU Feel free to conjecture, or for that matter add partial answers

Comment: Are these three friends related to each other in any manner?

Comment: @smriti They all live in the same world.

Comment: 3 different nanobots that kind of merge together to "assemble" into a slightly larger one? I didn't think about "they're all little" with my answer below.

Comment: I'm wondering if this has anything to do with *[Golden Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Sun_(series))* from Nintendo...

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain No.

Comment: I don't know about everyone else.. but this sounds like it has a planetary type ring to it or maybe mythology related

Comment: @Xylius, I thought so too, but I think that mythology (Gods, Titans, etc.) would run into a big hurdle here "I have three friends, they're all little..."

Comment: @user351579, there's a strong suggestion that your third friend is also your sister. Can you add any clarity there?

Comment: @John No, there is no blood relation between the friends and "myself".

Comment: @user351579, okay, I was reading too much into "and now in father's house she is." which shows possession by the speaker.

Comment: @user351579, is it related to Wreck-it Ralph?

Comment: @John No. (15chars)

Comment: It seems your friends are pokemons....;)

Comment: @John demigod pals?

Comment: Rock encrusted egg seems to imply geode, suggesting the children are gems. But why only three, and why specifically three, and more, why ANY three?

Comment: Also, this puzzle feels very computer-y, though that might just be because I'm focused on some of the words (Assemble for instance)

Comment: @ColdFrog You don't need a computer to solve this (although you need one to submit your answer, of course)

Comment: I meant more that the answer was related to computing than it would be required to solve, but I gotcha ;)

Comment: Anything to do with Star Wars given the Yoda style phrasing in the riddle? :)

Comment: @Ali I've been watching Star Wars recently, but no, the riddle itself is unrelated.

Comment: Maybe the third friend is clock(Something on that lines). As they say, "time is a great healer". Just guessing...

Comment: @Sid No, you are incorrect.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Goldbach conjecture, as the second friend could be a number assembled from prime numbers (a primal sum). Also the OP said "feel free to conjecture"

Comment: Anything to do with transformers? Optimus prime... felix... dark side of the moon?

Comment: I'm also speculating that the third friend could be Light or Electricity. But that  has no relation that I can see with prime numbers or eclipses.

Comment: @ErinL It's not about Transformers.

Comment: @VictorJalencas It's not about a mathematical conjecture.

Comment: Is the now waiting a tick of friend 3, related to an analogue to digital change?

Comment: @Ali No.(15chars)

Comment: subatomic particles perhaps? The third friend sounds like light or electricity…

Comment: can you post the solution please?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with modern or ancient medicine/alchemy? Based on Greek mythology? The staff of Caduceus or Asclepius? Wings, snake and stick assembled into a staff?
I've been thinking about this a lot. It does seem to fit in the description but I still have many missing pieces.

Comment: I'm still convinced a snake has something to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer , as sure about 1st Friend & 2nd. guess on 3rd.

Among 3 Friends

1st Friend :

> Cat
> As humans best/close friend is said to be Dog / Cat and in the riddle it is called as "Felix" a fictional character that would resemble cat.

2nd Friend :

> Quail (small Bird that would resemble)
> Assuming based on the Hint provided as it says hatched from eggs and three parts assembled forms the pet.

3rd Friend

> Rabbit

Partial Answer , as sure about 1st Friend & 2nd. guess on 3rd.

Comment: Do chickens have rock-encrusted eggs? ..... Anyway, it's not what was wanted. Your answer is not entirely incorrect though.

Comment: I suggest putting guesses and explanations in spoiler tag (>! in the beginning of a line)

Comment: Still mostly incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> [Chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(mythology))

The first friend is

> A Lion. He is the face of the chimera. Felix is a common name for cats.

The second is

> A goat. He is the second face of the chimera. I've seen him usually portrayed a bit more to the back I think. (I'm not claiming that is correct, just what I remember). Might have something to do with summoning the devil. I'd think twice before summoning the devil ;)

The third is

> A snake. The tail of the chimera. The logo of medicine features a snake on a cross. I believe also in some cultures it might have been seen as a god of healing. (not sure, will check later)

Put them together like a sum and you get

> Chimera!

Comment: Incorrect, try again.

Comment: Going in the correct general direction or am I completely off track? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is off-track. Though you have a little information that is _very slightly_ correct.

Comment: It seems his friends are pokemons....;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer...

I believe the third friend is:

> Mercury

This is because:

I have three friends, they're all little...

> It is one of the smaller planets

wherein there can be no eclipse

> Mercury has no moons, so it cannot have an eclipse

A beautiful healer she was

> Mercury was thought to heal, though now it is known to be poisonous

and now in father's house she is.

> In astrology, the fourth house is also known as the father and also the constellation Cancer, and mercury is in Cancer.

My third friend, she was very quick

> Mercury also known as Quicksilver

But now she always waits a tick,
I'm worried her work someone cuts.

> I'm least sure about this one, but mercury thermometers have been replaced by digital ones, so you can't watch them work, you have to wait!

Am I heading anywhere in the right direction?

Comment: You are not heading in the right direction.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know. So it's nothing to do with elements or planets?

Comment: No, it's not about them.

Comment: It's a very tough riddle! :)

Comment: We all know that a good Puzzling Stack Exchange question must be... well... puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

3rd friend:

> a leech. They used to be used for medicinal purposes and then fall in disgrace. Now in some parts, they are being used again in progressive or alternative medical practices

Comment: Sorry, you are incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :) As the OP said, your answer is not correct, please try to work upon it and incorporate as many clues in your answer as possible.

Answer (score 2):

### 1st attempt: Full Answer

The three friends together would be

> A sphinx : Woman's bust, Lion's body and tail and Bird wings !

First friend

> Lion : it's *almost* like a big cat... and its tail is always following the Sphinx!

Second friend

> Bird: I found this one more by deduction, but I'm not able to fully explain it.

Third friend

> Woman: because "she" is definitely a beautiful healer, and the hints #2 and #3 remind me the evolution of women status in western society : from the housewife to the modern working girl - it's a bit simplistic, I know, I'm sorry. By the way, it is interesting to post "Woman" as an answer on *International's woman day*, for a riddle created 2 years 1/2 ago! :)

### 2nd attempt: Partial Answer

First friend

> Cat: Felix is a name commonly used for cats

Second friend: I don't know

Third friend

> Ether: it used to be used as an anaesthetic, and if the "Father's house" means the "sky" (religious reference), then this can be ether as well.

If I didn't find the answer, which attempt is closer ?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer (1st friend only):

> Shadow 
>  Shadow is closest to one and follows him everyday. It has no color. In "the world with eclipse" there's no light so no shadow. Not sure about the Felix part (though after some googling, i think it might be related to peter pan).

Comment: Completely wrong.

Comment: ok will try more.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess
first friend

> A cat Pokemon
> (getting from Felix the cat)
>  Can be meowth

second friend

> Regigigas
>  It comes to life only when Regirock, Regice, and Registeel are gathered

third friend

> Healing type pokemon
>  not a clue about this yet

Comment: Not even in the right direction.

Comment: mmm...figured....

Answer (score 1):

Having a go at friend nr 2

> Moth
> Looks odd, 3(?) stages in life, cant go back.
> Many kinds: Aprox 160,000 species of moth.
> Rock eggs i don't know.
> It could basically be any other insect that goes through metamorphosis, and maybe some have rock encrusted eggs?

Comment: Sorry, you are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for the first and third friends.

Friend 1:

> Luck - "Felix" is all I really have here.

Friend 3:

> Time - "the times have changed", "time heals everything", grandfather clock

Comment: You are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 friends are:

> CO2, Glucose and Water. They are linked by the primal sum of photosynthesis

The first friend is

> CO2 follows you because you are constantly breathing it out

The second friend is

> Glucose is a compound made of child elements and photosynthesis is not reversible

The third friend is

> Water is the third friend but I can' quite figure out the coming when called bit - Is the living in father's house conversion to water vapor?

Comment: Nice observation, but sorry, you are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer

First friend base on the comment

> cat

Second friend

> Amphibian

That is the only creature that I can think base on the hint. I don't know the third but base on these two the answer should be

> Animals

Comment: Sorry, you are incorrect.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the answer? Answers without explanation are usually deleted.